# Set of discontinuous points of a bounded real function on $[a,b]$ is a $F_σ$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: Set of discontinuous points of a bounded real function on $[a,b]$ is a $F_σ$

I have no idea..Thanks for any hint or help in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson Sorry, I should add the word "prove"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a detailed proof but there are enough hints for you to complete the argument. Let $\omega (f,x)=\inf_{\delta >0} \sup \{|f(x)-f(y)|:|x-y| \leq \delta \}$. Show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $\omega (f,x)=0$. Then show that $\{x:\omega (f,x) \geq 1/n\}$ is a closed set for each $n$. The union of these sets is an $F_{\sigma}$ and it is the set of points of discontinuity of $f$.